# How to store query result in a variable in MySql stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to store the result (1 column) of a query in variable so that i can reuse it again in another queries for filtering

Ex:

student table

```
+----+------+------------+--------------+-------+
| id | name | dob        | email        | group |
+----+------+------------+--------------+-------+
| 1  | Sam  | 1990-12-12 | sam@test.com | 1     |
+----+------+------------+--------------+-------+
| 2  | Tom  | 1990-12-11 | tom@test.com | 1     |
+----+------+------------+--------------+-------+
| 3  | Kim  | 1990-11-11 | kim@test.com | 2     |
+----+------+------------+--------------+-------+
```

**Query**

```
select id from student  where  group=1;
```

this will give me

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 1  |
+----+
| 2  |
+----+
```

What I want to achieve is to store the above result in a variable so that i can reuse it in a Procedure like this in multiple queries.

```
select * from address where std_ref_id in (@theVariable);

select * from some_table where std_ref_id in (@theVariable);
```

Comment: and `mysql` or `sql-server`?

Comment: use 'temp' table or 'table' variable to store ids and can use the same in the IN clause for other SELECT statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better You need to use Temp Table or table variable to store the results set and for reuse it. Because variable can hold one value.

```
 if object_id('tempdb..#temp1') is not null
  drop table #temp1

select id  into #temp1 from student where group=1;
```

and then use temp table like below

```
select * from address a
join #temp1 t on a.std_ref_id =t.id
```

You can also use `table` variable. look below exampple

```
declare @temp as table
(
id int
) 
insert into @temp 
( 
id
)
select id  from student where group=1;
```

Then reuse it down..

```
select * from address a
join @temp t on a.std_ref_id =t.id
```

But there are differences between table variable and Temp tables in terms of it's scope etc.

Comment: In your examples you are using table "b" in JOIN but it should be table "t"